# Unable to do PHP+MySQL login with POST request

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, httpurlconnection

I am creating an app and when I click login in the android simulator it says unfortunately the app has stopped but I checked my code multiple times and I don't see any errors with the code . I am following a tutorial so it should all be correct because it works for the guy doing the tutorial .

**MainActivity.java :**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText UsernameEt, PasswordEt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    UsernameEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    PasswordEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

}

public void OnLogIn(View view) {
    String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
    String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);

}

}
```

**Backgroundworker.java :**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://192.168.1.7/login.php";
    if (type.equals("login")){
        try {
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name" , "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name , "UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("user_pass" , "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password , "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null ){
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

Login button in `content_main.xml` :

```
  <Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LogIn"
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="OnLogIn"
    />

  <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etUserName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

  <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etUserName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

**login.php :**

```
<?php
require"db.php";

$user_name = "user";
$password = "pass";

$mysql_qry = "select * from users where username = '$user_name' and password = '$password';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo"login success";
}
else {
echo"not success";
}
?>
```

**Error :**

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                               at com.example.User.App.MainActivity.OnLogIn(MainActivity.java:22)
>
> (line 22 mainactivity:  String username =
>   UsernameEt.getText().toString();)

Comment: `"... so it should all be correct because it works for the guy doing the tutorial"` -- until you know the source of your bug, **never** say this.

Comment: But I can't find the source of the bug that's the problem

Comment: Indeed, nor can I, but assume that there **is** a bug first, that you are wrong somewhere. Otherwise you'll be eating your words.

Comment: can you show your android logcat

Comment: Try to debug the code and find the point where it is crashing..So that it will be easy to find the bug in the code..

Comment: What's that ? @ChannaJayamuni

Comment: Android runtime log

Comment: I only see an event log @ChannaJayamuni

Comment: Either print out the response from the server or add more exception handling, but first, please refer to this post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @cricket_007 this is what it says : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: at com.example.User.App.MainActivity.OnLogIn(MainActivity.java:22)

Comment: public void OnLogIn(View view) {
    String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
    String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);

Comment: The code where the error is is at string username .... But I can't find the problem at all

Comment: @cricket_007 I just did

Comment: That error is likely caused by referencing the wrong xml ids in the code. I've updated my answer below

Comment: please update your `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` xml also

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix the app crashing, such as making sure `activity_main.xml` (or `content_main`, if you have one) contains those two button ids that you've used in the code, you have a second problem with the server as well.

Your PHP file always uses `user:pass` as the credentials to try to login to the database, and never receives anything else.

If you would like to get the values that android set in the POST request, you can do like so

```
if (isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['user_pass'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $password = $_POST['user_pass'];

    // TODO: Call database function
```

Comment: Not sure why you say they are the same ids. `android:id="@+id/editText"` does not say `etUserName`

Comment: Did you correct both of the ids? Username and password?

Comment: yes .         android:id="@+id/UsernameEt"
        android:id="@+id/PasswordEt"

Comment: Okay. Stop messing with the XML. Make sure that the Java code R.id values are the exact same as the XML id values. Because what you just said, they still are not the same

Comment: Whenever I it the way you told me too when I click the login button it doesn't work

Comment: Okay, so if the ids are the exact same, and you are 100% sure of that, then you either have no errors, or the error message is different. In either case, update your question again with the correct xml and the error message

Comment: android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etUserName"

Comment: android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etUserName"

Comment: the same as the java

Comment: Then you have a different error message. Like I said, please update your question with the new code

Comment: You'll need to fix the other id `android:layout_below="@+id/textView"`, but still, you should not be getting the same error as before, so please update that as well, even if it looks the same

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in server side. Here, `NullPointerException` in EditText means you are getting value from `Edittext`, that is not initialized.

**Possible cause** of `NullPointerException` is:

1. You are using multi-screen layout. That means your each layout has multiple copy in multiple layout folder. And your device suitable folder not contains desired `EditText`.

**Solution**:
   make sure `etUserName` is in your desired xml.

Comment: Read the comments under my answer. OP did fix the code, just didn't bother updating the question with the actual error. Plus, look at the PHP, there is a logical error in how the values are retrieved and queried.